# List FTP files with goftp

Tags: go, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to write a simple Go program which connects to an FTP server, list the files in a specified directory and pulls them.

The code is this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/secsy/goftp"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    config := goftp.Config{
        User:               "anonymous",
        Password:           "root@local.me",
        ConnectionsPerHost: 21,
        Timeout:            10 * time.Second,
        Logger:             os.Stderr,
    }

    // Connecting to the server
    client, dailErr := goftp.DialConfig(config, "ftp.example.com")

    if dailErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(dailErr)
        panic(dailErr)
    }
    // setting the search directory
    dir := "/downloads/"
    files, err := client.ReadDir(dir)

    if err != nil {
        for _, file := range files {
            if file.IsDir() {
                path.Join(dir, file.Name())
            } else {
                fmt.Println("the file is %s", file.Name())
            }
        }
    }
    // this section works , I am setting a file name and I can pull it
    // if I mark the search part
    ret_file := "example.PDF"

    fmt.Println("Retrieving file: ", ret_file)
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    fullPathFile := dir + ret_file
    rferr := client.Retrieve(fullPathFile, buf)

    if rferr != nil {
        panic(rferr)
    }

    fmt.Println("writing data to file", ret_file)

    fmt.Println("Opening file", ret_file, "for writing")
    w, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    ferr := ioutil.WriteFile(ret_file, w, 0644)

    if ferr != nil {
        log.Fatal(ferr)
        panic(ferr)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Writing", ret_file, " completed")
    }
}
```

For some reason I am getting an error on the `ReadDir` function.
I need to grab the files names so I can download them.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to loop through `files` when `ReadDir()` returns an error. That will never work, as any time an error is returned `files` is `nil`.

This is pretty standard behavior and can be confirmed by reading [the implementation of `ReadDir()`](https://github.com/secsy/goftp/blob/aa2de14babf4377c60f2d9614a7e52021285f341/file_system.go#L127-L162).

I'm guessing you may have used the [the example from the project used to demonstrate `ReadDir()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/secsy/goftp#example-Client.ReadDir-ParallelWalk) as a starting point. Within the example, the error handling is involved because it's deciding whether or not to continue walking the directory tree. However, note that [when `ReadDir()` returns an error that doesn't result in stopping the program, the subsequent for loop is a no-op](https://github.com/secsy/goftp/blob/aa2de14babf4377c60f2d9614a7e52021285f341/parallel_walk_test.go#L50-L60), since `files` is `nil`.

Here's a small program that demonstrates successfully using the results of `Readdir()` in a straightforward manner:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/secsy/goftp"
)

const (
    ftpServerURL = "ftp.us.debian.org"
    ftpServerPath = "/debian/"
)

func main() {
    client, err := goftp.Dial(ftpServerURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    files, err := client.ReadDir(ftpServerPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file.Name())
    }
}
```

It outputs (which matches the current listing at http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/):

```sh
$ go run goftp-test.go
README
README.CD-manufacture
README.html
README.mirrors.html
README.mirrors.txt
dists
doc
extrafiles
indices
ls-lR.gz
pool
project
tools
zzz-dists
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response , I have updated my code and it looks as it is working with the FTP server you mentioned.
my problem is that I am using a BROTHER printer which comes with a build-in FTP server and when I run the code with my printer values I receive an I/O timeout Error

Comment: panic: error reading response: read tcp 192.168.1.1:45312->192.168.1.2:21: i/o timeout

Comment: FTP is a finicky protocol. You may want to try enabling [the `DisableEPSV` option within a custom `Config`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bobcashstory/goftp#Config) and then using `DialConfig()`. Also, in your code snippet, you state `this section works , I am setting a file name and I can pull it`. Is that no longer the case?